# Opening PDF inline in a frame - how to set the file name?

Tags: php, firefox, pdf

While rendering a PDF inside a frame in Firefox inline, the file name is ignored (click on save as after the PDF opens, and the name of the frame is shown in the save box, instead of the file name).  I tried header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename=abc.pdf'); - it doesn't work.  The same code works for attachment though, just doesn't work for inline.  How to fix this?

This is in PHP, FF 15 and on windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot set a file name while embedding the PDF in a frame or a browser tab

- you change the title of the frame
- you make another button for download where you force the user to download with your custom name